# h1 and p elements inside two inline-block divs trouble

Tags: css, inline

I got a problem with `h1` and `p` element inside a couple of inline-blocked divs.

**Here's the code:**

```css
#map-canvas {
  width:    69%;
  height:   1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#filter-manager{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#filter-manager h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-manager">
  <h1>Filtri</h1>
</div><!-- #filter-manager -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div><!-- #map-canvas -->
```

The divs keep their inline status but `#filter-manager` goes on the bottom when I put a `h1` or p element. If I don't put anything inside the divs are aligned perfectly.

Why `h1` and `p` elements do behave like that?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have 2 solutions. First is to add this:

```
#filter-manager {
        float: left;
}
```

Second is to make h1 `table` :

```
#filter-manager h1 {
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add vertical-align:top in the div with display:inline-block; Also , you dont need display:block in h1 because is by default in h1,h2,h3 etc..

```css
#map-canvas {
  width:    69%;
  height:   100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  vertical-align:top
}
#filter-manager{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align:top
}
#filter-manager h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-manager">
  <h1>Filtri</h1>
</div><!-- #filter-manager -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div><!-- #map-canvas -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the display of the h1 in the css file.

If that does not work try and check the `width:30%` and `margin:0` parameters your problem is definitely in there.

Comment: As you can see, I tried display:block and margin:0 for the h1 element. 
I tried even width: 20% but the problem isn't there and anything changes :/